# Send MQTT Connect Packet over TCP in c

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, mqtt

I am trying to send MQTT connect packets over TCP. I am using windows platform and using VC express edition.  I Have successfully implemented Basic server-client application over TCP. However i have no idea about how to send mqtt  packets over TCP as i am fairly new in socket programming. Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 3):

Before starting you should know what you are dealing with. First study how the MQTT protocol works, then proceed to the programming aspect of MQTT. Although you need to understand various other aspects of socket programming before proceeding to MQTT. I'll mention a few resources to help you out.

For Documentation & Specification

[MQTT Website](http://mqtt.org)

[MQ Telemetry Transport (MQTT) V3.1 Protocol Specification](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-mqtt/)

[Paho - MQTT client library for C](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c)

[Paho - MQTT client library for C (Documentation)](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/Cclient/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.. I have gone through all these documents and i know about the protocol specification. What i really wanted was a blog or article which has an example of how it can be implemented in windows.

Comment: Look, have you taken a look at PAHO. Its all source code + it might have some tests. You can look at those tests as examples of using the library.